# How to create a zip file from Azure blob storage container files using Pipeline

Tags: azure, containers, blob, azure-pipelines, zip

I have some dynamically created files in a blob storage container. I want to send it through email as a single attachment.

The total file size is less than 5 MB.
But here the difficulty I am facing is, when I try to compress the file using CopyData options, the compressed/zipped file not creating properly with multiple files.

If I try to zip a single file by giving its full path and filename, it is working fine. But when I give a folder name to compress all the files in that folder, it is not working correctly.

Please note that here I am not using any kind of external C# code or libraries.
[image]

Any help appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Why the Azure Pipelines tag? That's for build pipelines in Azure DevOps? Is this an Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Comment: Please add more information on what you mean by not working correctly.

Comment: @junnas this is an Azure data factory pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference my settings in Data Factory Copy active:

**Source settings**:

[image]

**Source dataset settings**:

[image]

**Sink settings**:

[image]

**Sink dataset settings**:

[image]

**Pipeline works ok**:

[image]

**Check the zip file** in contianer `containerleon`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. it is working fine. May I know how to specify a proper file name for this output zip file ? Can we create RAR file instead of zip file with this same method ?

Comment: Sorry,  can not specify the compressed file name now. The compressed file only support BZip2, GZip, Deflate, Zipdeflate.